# How do I view flash objects in Firefox in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, flash

How do I view flash objects in Firefox in Ubuntu? I can't seem to get flash working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow [this guide](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu:Jaunty#Adobe_Flash_Player_for_Firefox_Plug-in) for Ubuntu Jaunty Jackaloupe to install the Flash Player plugin. Basically, you just need to run this in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the [ubuntu-restricted-extras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu-restricted-extras) package installed? If not, install that:

> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras

This package gives you these capabilities:

> Installing this package will pull in support for MP3 playback and decoding, support for various other audio formats (GStreamer plugins), Microsoft fonts, Java runtime environment, Flash plugin, LAME (to create compressed audio files), and DVD playback.

If you do have this package installed, but are having problems getting flash to work in Firefox, work your way through the [Troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/Flash#Troubleshooting) section of the Ubuntu Community Documentation on Flash. You may also be interested in the [free software alternatives](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/Flash#Free%20Software%20alternatives%20to%20Adobe%27s%20Flash%20Player) to Adobe's Flash Player.

**Update:** This package is present in the Ubuntu *multiverse* repository. Enable this by following the Ubuntu Community Documentation instructions on adding [repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) if you cannot find this package in your system.

Comment: Error Message: Could find package ...

Comment: I've replied to your related question on this error. You'll need to enable the multiverse repository on your system.